# Bypassing Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, cookies, excel, hyperlink

The problem i am facing is that I have a spreadsheet that pulls data from an intranet site that stores credentials in a cookie on the browser. My macro does authenticate into the site via internet explorer, but the hyperlinks i add to the data that lead back to the site will open in the default browser of the user. Is there a way to change which browser the Hyperlinks method will open, or is there a way to forward the request directly to the default browser of the user without going through Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery? Hyperlinks in Outlook open directly to the default browser, is there a reason excel does not? Or is there a way to somehow grab that cookie and send it with the request? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your links to point back to the cell which contains them, you can trap the FollowHyperlink event (at the worksheet or workbook level) and use that to open the link in IE. Assuming you can put the full link as "Text to display".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim url As String
    url = Target.TextToDisplay
    'automate IE to open the link...
End Sub
```

Comment: I was considering using something similar to this method, but I like your solution more than what i was considering. If i don't get a response that will allow me to bypass it somehow, i will use this. I just wonder if there is a way that won't require me to write it like this as it would require a lot of new code for various different reasons that I won't get into at this point.

Comment: **Note: TextToDisplay didn't work. I ended up having to use ScreenTip after I realized that I was supposed to reference the cell itself (I didn't read this closely enough). It works great now. Thanks!

Comment: `TextToDisplay` was OK for me, since I was using the actual URL for that property.  Glad to hear you got it working.